# android:screenOrientation="portrait" is ignored in Jellybean

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

android:screenOrientation="portrait" is ignored in Jellybean. If I turn the phone into landscape it will change orientation regardless. I have tried on several phones. Is there any new flag I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do it programmatically,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    switch (newConfig.orientation)
    {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        // taking action on event
        lockScreenRotation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        // taking action on event
        lockScreenRotation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE:
        // taking action on event
        lockScreenRotation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE);
    break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unexpected orientation!!!");
    break;
 }




private void lockScreenRotation(int orientation)
    {
      // Stop the screen orientation changing during an event
        switch (orientation)
        {
        ...
      case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;
      case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;
        ...
      case default:
       this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED); 
       break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, will try it out ASAP. Will ask the google group aswell what the heck is wrong.