# android:screenOrientation="portrait" is not working on one Chinese Pad

Tags: android-listview, orientation, android

I have made app and set it to have `portrait` orientation for main `<activity>` in `ActivityManifest.xml`. It is `portrait` on all devices except one Chinese noname pad. 
There are other apps that handle orientation on that pad correctly.

I expect that in portrait orientation screen width is less then height.

My 2 questions are:-

1. What is the best way to set orientation? Do I have to check screen width/height and rotate screen accordingly?
2. How widespread that orientation bug is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActivityManifest.xml` way is good enough.
My buggy noname chinese pad is only device that I seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844577/androidscreenorientation-portrait-is-ignored-in-jellybean) answer. That was for a Jellybean bug but the same code may apply for other versions aswell.

Comment: I have Nexus 4 with Jellybean and it works fine with orientation. Right now I can't test it on chinese pad as this pad also have very bad(dead) battery. I will try to test it once it will return to live.